# How do I make suggest command public to all servers? discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a suggest command on my bot that im working on. However it only works when the user suggesting is in my server since it is codded to send the suggestion to a specific channel id. Is there a way to code it where the suggestion comes to my dms or specified channel even if the user suggesting isn't in the server? here is my code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  if (!args.length) {
    return message.channel.send("Please Give the Suggestion")
  }

  let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => (x.name === "sauce-supplier-suggestions" || x.name === "sauce-supplier-suggestions"))

  if (!channel) {
    return message.channel.send("there is no channel with name - sauce-supplier-suggestions")
  }

  let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("SUGGESTION: " + message.author.tag, message.author.avatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
    .setColor("#ff2050")
    .setDescription(args.join(" "))
    .setTimestamp()

  channel.send(embed).then(m => {
    m.react("✅")
    m.react("❌")
  })
  message.channel.send("sucsessfully sent your suggestion to bot team thank you for your suggestion!!")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some small changes in your code. Now if a user uses the command correctly, the bot will send you a DM with the users suggestion.

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  let suggestion = args.join(" ");
  let owner = client.users.cache.get("YOUR ID");

  if (!suggestion) {
    return message.channel.send("Please Give the Suggestion")
  }

  let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find((x) => (x.name === "sauce-supplier-suggestions" || x.name === "sauce-supplier-suggestions"))

  if (!channel) {
    return message.channel.send("there is no channel with name - sauce-supplier-suggestions")
  }

  let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("SUGGESTION: " + message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setColor("#ff2050")
    .setDescription(suggestion)
    .setTimestamp()

  owner.send(embed).then(m => {
    m.react("✅")
    m.react("❌")
  })
  message.channel.send("sucsessfully sent your suggestion to bot team thank you for your suggestion!!")
}
```

Comment: so I checked the code again, turns out all I had to remove was the `if (!channel) {
    return message.channel.send("there is no channel with name - sauce-supplier-suggestions")
  }` and that solved my problem! thank you so much